# DataBricks Pyspark DATEADD

Tags: azure, pyspark, databricks

I'm trying to filter out data from the current date to last 3 years and trying to use this for Pyspark dataframe.

below sql query needs to convert into Pyspark dataframe format

date >= dateadd(month,-4,current_date)

How to write above sql in Pyspark dataframe format

Comment: yes i am using Azure Databricks

Answer (score 0):

Lets create a dataframe to test on:

```
from datetime import date,timedelta
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
start_date = date(2023,1,1)
dates_list = []
for i in range(0,12):
    curr_date = start_date + relativedelta(months=i)
    print(curr_date)
    dates_list.append((i+1,curr_date))
columns =["id","date"]
dates_df = spark.createDataFrame(dates_list,columns)
```

These create a dataframe with 12 rows, each for the 1 day of the month in 2023:

```
display(dates_df)
```

[image: dates_df]

Now lets filter the dataframe into a new dataframe:

```
filter_dates_df = dates_df.where("date>=dateadd(month,-4,current_date)")
```

And the results:

```
display(filter_dates_df)
```

[image: filter_dates_df]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a combination of the [filter](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.1/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.filter.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.filter) and [add_months](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.1/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.add_months.html#pyspark.sql.functions.add_months) functions, like this:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = df.filter(F.col("date") >= F.add_months(F.current_date(), -4))
```